# expert system in dot net

Tags: .net

Asal-o-Alikum

My final project is about an expert system of a medical center.

I have to implement it in .NET and I want to ask that is it possible in .NET to code a system that behave like a decision making system on the behalf of data in data base?

E.g. a new patient come to doctor and doctor use the system and system suggest a diagnose, test or medicine on the base of relevant data about previous patients.

Comment: C#, VB.NET and the other .NET languages are fully fledged programming languages. Therefore the answer would most probably be "Yes.", if this is a possible task at all.

Comment: .NET isn't a language it's a framework. The languages that implement .NET are C# and VB.NET. There's nothing in the either language that would stop you implementing an expert system.

Answer (score 3):

There are no reasons for it to be not possible, but you have to implement the deciding algorithm. Using a decision tree-algorithm can be a good start.

Comment: can u please suggest me any meterial about that coz i have no knowldge about expert system

Comment: I am not sure if it will be enough, but you can start with trying some decision-tree algorithms: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)